# I Can't Get Datatables to chance it's source (number of columns, etc.)

Tags: entity-framework, datatables, entity-framework-6

It still thinks its on the previous Entity Framework Source. Any thoughts?

[image]

Comment: You mean "Change it's source"? Is this code first or database first (EDMX)? For DB first see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/database-first-development/changing-the-database).

Comment: Steve, This answers my Question completely. Also, I didn't realize that dealing with datatables on the server side is different. Thank You! How do I give you points?

Comment: No worries, it is just a link. Glad it worked.